# Error with NSDictionary - 'Count of objects differs from count of keys'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, crash-reports

I just got a crash report (at launch), after submitting my app to the Mac App Store, for review :

```
Application Specific Information:
objc[1832]: garbage collection is ON
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (2)'
terminate called throwing an exception
abort() called
```

This is the part of code, I'm suspecting :

```
- (NSMutableDictionary*)getNewChapterWithTitle:(NSString*)title
{
    if (title==nil) title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chapter %d",[[self appChapters] count]+1];

    // Align Justify
    NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    [paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSJustifiedTextAlignment];

    // Set Font
    NSDictionary *font = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Garamond" size:15.0],paragraphStyle, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFontAttributeName, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil]];

    NSString* lipsum = @"\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc consequat fermentum faucibusPhasellus ac consequat metus. Sed at lectus sit amet tellus vulputate mollis vel suscipit metus. Nulla a sapien purus. Aenean sollicitudin lacus varius nisi faucibus nec lacinia mauris fermentum. Aliquam euismod quam rhoncus ipsum pulvinar quis condimentum magna imperdiet. Nullam augue leo, dictum tincidunt ullamcorper id, porta in lorem. Duis in vestibulum nisl.\
    \n\n\
    Donec imperdiet dignissim massa, at ultricies enim dignissim at. Etiam pharetra neque quis quam condimentum vitae viverra nisl volutpat. Vivamus urna ante, ultrices ut tincidunt id, auctor id est. Nunc eget diam purus, at viverra orci. Maecenas eu magna mi, id venenatis arcu. Maecenas ornare, tortor sit amet gravida placerat, diam urna lacinia nunc, a dictum arcu libero sed metus. Nulla pulvinar sapien vitae lectus faucibus quis tempus elit volutpat. Integer facilisis interdum lectus, sit amet dapibus enim mattis non. Donec sed pulvinar risus. Mauris in nulla urna, sit amet placerat turpis. Proin felis erat, pretium sed pharetra vel, tincidunt quis tortor. Donec ut nisi dui. Pellentesque gravida gravida justo, quis convallis leo euismod in. Nam pretium accumsan sapien ac interdum.";

    NSMutableAttributedString* theLipsum = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lipsum attributes:font];

    return [[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            [title retain],@"title",
            [theLipsum retain],@"content",
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"isMarkdown",
            nil] retain];
}
```

Do you see anything "obviously" wrong with the above? (It's being called like 4-5 times, from `awakeFromNib`, so I guess that's the culprit...)

---

**HINT :** The `retain`s have been added after the report; I don't know if it's going to help though at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[NSFont fontWithName:@"Garamond" size:15.0]` probably returns `nil`. As far as I know it's not a default font on OSX. So your objects array is empty, because only the objects up until the first `nil` are added.

Comment: @Remizorrr Guys, thanks a LOT! Hadn't even thought of that; will check out how it goes, and will replace the font in-question if needed. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is here - `[NSFont fontWithName:@"Garamond" size:15.0]`
This code returns nil, so the array is empty.

May be this font is not standard but it is installed on your computer.
if the problem is here, you should add this font to app resources.